# SAS: PROC SGPLOT BY GROUP auto file names

Tags: plot, sas, sas-ods

I am plotting some data using BY GROUP option. While I am able to use #byval option to automatically put BY GROUP value in title of each plot, but I want to save each plot individually and want to name it after #byval instead of calling it - SGPLOT01, SGPLOT02 ...

e.g. Lets say I have:

```
data xyz;
input type$ x y1 y2@@;
cards;
A 1 5 7
A 2 7 9
A 3 8 10
B 1 5 7
B 2 7 9
B 3 8 10
;;
RUN;

PROC SGPLOT DATA=xyz;
by type;
series1 x=x y=y1/markers;
series2 x=x y=y2/markers;
title "#byval";
RUN;
```

In this example, two plots will be created one each for type A and B. But program will automatically name them as SGPLOT1.pdf and SGPLOT2.pdf. I would rather want to name them A.pdf and B.pdf, and want to save them to directory "C:/SGPLOTS/".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use ODS and put use a macro to print each TYPE separately, like in the following example.

```
data xyz;
input type$ x y1 y2 @@;
cards;
A 1 5 7
A 2 7 9
A 3 8 10
B 1 5 7
B 2 7 9
B 3 8 10
;
RUN;

ods listing close;

%macro plot_it(type=);

   goptions reset
      device = sasprtc
      target = sasprtc
      ;

   ods pdf file="C:/SGPLOTS/&type..pdf" notoc;

   PROC SGPLOT DATA=xyz;
   by type;
   where type = "&type";
   series x=x y=y1/markers;
   series x=x y=y2/markers;
   title "#byval";
   RUN;

   ods pdf close;

%mend plot_it;

%plot_it(type=A);
%plot_it(type=B);
```

Comment: ... and you could use `call execute` to replace the hardcoded macro calls if there were a large number of types.

Answer (score -1):

You want to add the variable name within parentheses, after #BYVAL.  In this example you want to put  #byval(type)    in your title.

I have put your example within something SAS calls an "HTML sandwich," which is two lines on top and two lines on the bottom.  In addition I added the helpbrowser option, which tells SAS to use its own capabilities to display the html output.

```
option helpbrowser=sas;

/**** top of html sandwich *****/
ods html ;
ods graphics on; 
/*******************************/


data xyz;
input type$ x y1 y2@@;
cards;
A 1 5 7
A 2 7 9
A 3 8 10
B 1 5 7
B 2 7 9
B 3 8 10
;;
RUN;

PROC SGPLOT DATA=xyz;
by type;
series x=x y=y1/markers;
series x=x y=y2/markers;
title "Here is the type:  #byval(type)";
RUN;


/**** bottom of html sandwich *****/
ods graphics off;
ods html close;
/**********************************/
```